# Javascript to identify controls of a particular column

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to get all controls of a Grid.

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGridLevel4_GridData").getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Is it possible for me to get controls of a particular column alone?

Comment: will you please give more detail..

Comment: Sure..The above code returns me the controls of the entire Grid. But all i want is controls from a specific column. For example if i have 2 columns "A","B". i want controls from Column "A" alone.

Comment: If that grid is a `TABLE` element, you can use its `cells[n]` property to refer a specific column by index number (of total number of columns in that grid). You can also use `rows[y].cells[x]` if you want to refer by row and column.